# querying a time stored as string in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, datetime, nosql

I have a collection in mongodb where i store the date and time strings separately. Each document looks like thisL

Date: "05/16/2014",
  Time: "11:00",
  Coach: {
    coachId: "15b62940-1df8-42df-a30e-d52f4169c9f8",
    coachName: "xxxxxx xxxxx",
    coachPhone: "(xxx) xxx-xxxx"
  },
  _id: "53766924d95930406a3d5b4e"

If i'm searching for documents within a specific time range form a Node js client, whats the best way to do it. Can this be at query time of do i need to store the date and time in a different format for the $lte, $get etc operators to work
Thanks

Comment: by amazing coincidence I just published this morning http://www.kamsky.org/stupid-tricks-with-mongodb/working-with-dates-that-are-strings which shows how you can transform strings in a way that allows you to group/aggregate by them.   Are you just searching or do you need to process or aggregate the data as well?

Comment: Do you mean a time range regardless of day?  If so you can simply filter on `Time` using `$lte`, etc. as long as `Time` is in 24H format.

Answer (score 1):

By abstracting a point in time in form of two strings, you are making life miserable for you. Especially when you use the US date format on which alphabetic sorting doesn't work.

Whenever you work with points in time in MongoDB, you should use [the building Date](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#date) type. In NodeJS, this type maps directly to the Javascript Date type. When you need to format the date in a more readable form than the normal toString(), you can easily do so on the frontend.

On the database layer, using the BSON Date allows you to [sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) by date and to use the [date-based query operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) in aggregation.

But when you insist on keeping it that way, you could use a [$where-query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) to use a Javascript function to convert the date-string and time-string to a javascript Date object and then perform date-arithmetics on it. This might work, but it will be a very slow and ugly solution you could avoid by storing your date as a Date.

Comment: no!!! not the $where!!!  :)  How about using aggregation framework instead?  It lets you transform the field to a form that will be ... usable...

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I don't think the aggregation framework will help here. The aggregation date operators can extract information from a date and do arithmetics with dates, but they can not create a new date from bits and pieces of information.

Comment: Thanks Philipp. I'll explore the mongo Date type as you suggest and handle the display on the front-end. 
Thaks everyone for their replies

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Would you like to show us how by writing an own answer?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue based on recommendation from Philipp. 
From my client controller that saves data, i sent in a Date type.

```
var dateString = $('#datetimepicker').val();
var date = new Date(dateString);
$scope.AvailDates.push( {DateUTC:**date**});
```

The AvailDates is sent via http post to be saved to my mongodb where it gets saved as as a Mongo Date type:

```
{DateUTC: "2014-05-20T15:30:00.000Z"}
```

When another client does a date based search, I send the date in the same format as the saving client and then do a .toISOString() on it:

```
var inputUTCDate =new Date(req.params.datetime);
```

when sending the search to the database, I do this:

```
collection.find({DateUTC:{$gte:inputUTCDate.toISOString()}).toArray(function(err, items) {}
```

On the inputUTCDate, i can add/subtract time if i need time ranges and use the $get and $lte operators and they work fine